# Battery pack voltage keeps dropping without use

Tags: batteries, nimh

I have a battery pack for a circa 2008 Black & Decker 9.6 V electrical screwdriver. It was not holding a charge so I replaced its batteries. It had eight NiCd 1200 mAh batteries. I replaced them with new NiMh 1500 mAh ones (these were available to me). I charged them with the original charger for 6 hours. I measured the battery pack open circuit voltage at 10.96 V afterwards.

Next day I repeated the measurement, and it was 10.75 V. I never used the device and in fact, did not install the battery pack on the device.

- Measurement two days after charging: 10.65 V
- Measurement five days after charging: 10.56 V

Is this normal for the type of batteries used?

[image]

Comment: You have also replaced the batteries with ones of different chemistry. The voltages and charge profiles are different. I don't know what the charging circuitry is but it's probable that it was not designed to deal with NIMH batteries.

Comment: @vir I appreciate your comment, but I honestly do not see how the charger could be presented as a factor.  The NIMH batteries do not know how they are being charged.  I am assuming the charger is providing a 'standard' charge for 6 hours.  I don't think the charger has any intelligence to it.  And I don't believe there are specialized chargers for NIMH batteries.  Such batteries also do not have BMS components designed for them.  I am not well-versed in 'constant voltage, constant current' knowledge, but the three phase charging of lead-acid batteries probably does not apply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nickel metal hydride batteries have a relatively high self discharge rate.  [Battery University](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-802b-what-does-elevated-self-discharge-do) says that they lose 10 to 15 percent of charge over the first 24 hours.  That loss of charge will result in a lower battery voltage.

BU provides this self-discharge rate diagram for nickel based batteries:

[image]

Note that the diagram is charge state, not voltage.  Voltage is related to charge state, but not in a simple way.  About all you can say is that lower charge means lower voltage.

In other words:

Yes, it is to be expected that the voltage slowly drops with NiMh batteries.

Comment: Much appreciated.  I was thinking that the batteries might somehow be bad.